# Why isn't my UITextField Coming up (trying to use autoconstraints), without CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, constraints, cgrect

A textfield comes up when I uncomment the CGRect but will not come up if I comment it out. If I use the CGrect, my constraints will not work.

```
let createTextField: TextFieldBounds = {
    //var myTextField = TextFieldBounds(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
       var myTextField = TextFieldBounds ()
        myTextField.insetX = 45
        //let myTextField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
        myTextField.placeholder = "fillertext" //set placeholder text
        myTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14) // set font size of text field
        myTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 //set width
        myTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor//set background color to a ui color
        myTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = myTextField.frame.height/2
        myTextField.autocorrectionType = .no // disable autocorrect when typing for .no, enable with .yes
        myTextField.isSecureTextEntry = true// masked text
        myTextField.keyboardType = .default //keyboard style is set to default
        myTextField.returnKeyType = .default //retuen key text changed to "Done" instead of return
        myTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        myTextField.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
        return myTextField
    }()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(createTextField)
    setupUserName()
}

private func setupUserName() {
    createTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: (self.view.frame.height * (400/812))) .isActive = true
    createTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: (self.view.frame.width * (35/375))) .isActive = true
    createTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -(self.view.frame.width * (35/375))) .isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this line of code:

```
myTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

also add some height:

```
myTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Comment: @bain great! Kindly mark the answer as accepted by pressing the Tick icon on left of my answer.

Comment: I think maybe because I don't have enough reputation it won't let me mark it, I am new on here. Also for some reason my corner radius are not rounding like when I used cgrect with this function myTextField.layer.cornerRadius = myTextField.frame.height/2

Comment: @bain can you accept the answer now? Now that you have good reputation points.